# The "tag" plugin does not exist

Tags: 8

The issue is about page loading like the following ones:

1. Front page
2. Taxonomy pages (for instance, https://talash.by/taxonomy/term/33)
3. Any view pages in edit mode /admin/structure/views/view/block_content
4. Content list page /admin/content
5. User list page /admin/people

I have a message "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Apache log shows:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The "tag" plugin does not exist." at /var/www/site/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php line 52,

The issue happens even if I make a site copy (files and database) on the same physical server, but as different virtual server. Internal pages can be loaded (for example, https://talash.by/terms-of-use)

I am using Drupal 8.2.4 (standard) on Ubuntu 16.04, with PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli).

These are the non-core modules:

- Media                Colorbox (colorbox)                               Module  Not installed  8.x-1.2

  - Other                Backup and Migrate (backup_migrate)               Module  Not installed  8.x-4.0-alpha1
  - Other                Colorbox Inline (colorbox_inline)                 Module  Not installed  8.x-1.0-rc2
  - Other                Disqus (disqus)                                   Module  Enabled        8.x-1.0-rc3
  - Other                Exclude node title (exclude_node_title)           Module  Not installed  8.x-1.0-beta1+7-dev
  - Other                Ultimate Cron (ultimate_cron)                     Module  Not installed  8.x-2.0-alpha1
  - Web services         HAL (hal)
    Bootstrap            Bootstrap (bootstrap)
  - Theme   Enabled        8.x-3.1
    Bootstrap            Bootstrap Clean Blog (bootstrap_clean_blog)
  - Theme   Enabled        8.x-1.0-rc2

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! While it could be clear what you are saying, it's not clear what you are asking, since you aren't asking any explicit question. Stack Exchange doesn't work well with implicit questions. What don't you understand? What did you find about that error message? What don't you understand in the given explanation?

Comment: I have the same problem after our webserver switched from MySQL to MariaDB

Answer (score 2):

Tag is the views cache plugin: \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\cache\Tag, that is in core.

If you are missing that then the files of your installation are messed up, you are possibly missing other files as well. You might want to re-upload all files and also consider using a more reliable deployment method like composer and not upload files over FTP or so.

Comment: Many thanks. You are right. The main problem was because of wrong configuration of a .gitignore file in the root folder. It had a string with a word "cache" and when I made a clone on the production server it does not download a folder itself and all files inside this "core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/cache". 

The next step is to figure out how to keep integrity of the project with composer.

Thanks!